# Search and replace with quote in batch script

Tags: search, batch-file, replace

I'm trying to search and replace a string containing a double quote with another string but I got some issue.

I'm reading a file line per line, and searching in this line if there's a match for a replace

Example:

`%%l` contain a line read from a file. For this example, `%%l` = `myVar: "../folder"+var`

```
set s=%%l
set sch="+var
set rpl=val
set s=%s:!sch!=!rpl!%
echo !s!
```

Here, I want to replace `"+var` with `val`

But doing this, it's not working. My `echo !s!` return `"+var=val` only

I also tried:

```
set s=%%l
set rpl=val
set s=%s:"+var=!rpl!%
```

And it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing replace line for this:

```
set s=!s:%sch%=%rpl%!
```